# Flex compile problem with as3httpclient

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, compiler-construction

I am having trouble getting a Flex application (with as3httpclient) to work.
I compiled it (compc -load-config=build-swc.xml), put the as3httpclientlib-1_0_6.swc in my libs dir, and ran

```
mxmlc -compiler.include-libraries lib/as3crypto-1_3_patched.swc 
lib/as3httpclientlib-1_0_6.swc lib/corelib.swc -- App.mxml
```

In my actionscript I

```
import org.httpclient.HttpClient;
```

but still I receive the error

```
Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: HttpStatusEvent
client.listener.onStatus = function(event:HttpStatusEvent):void {
```

...
. Any ideas?

btw / before compiling "compc -load-config=build-swc.xml" I hade to 
change

```
  <path-element>${flexlib}/libs/player/9/playerglobal.swc</path-element>
```

to

```
  <path-element>${flexlib}/libs/player/10.0/playerglobal.swc</path-element>
```

in order for it to compile because my flex version doesn't have a playerglobal.swc for Flash 9. 8o

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a custom defined class, there is no such thing as HttpStatusEvent, you need to import flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent and refer to it as such.